# Text doesn't appear in render. (File attached)

Tags: rendering, animation, text-object, 2d

New to blender. Created a 2D animation. Text doesn't appear in render. File attached. Please help. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text objects and the grease pencil drawings lie in the same plane. Visibility is therefore depending on the drawing order, also Z-fighting may occur. I would suggest to move the text slightly along the Y-axis in order to position it in front of the grease pencil drawing. Another approach is to change the *Stroke Depth Order* for the grease pencil objects from *2D Layers* to *3D Location*. This seems to work as well, although Z-fighting may still occur.

Comment: Moved it. Works. Thank You rjg.